# What's causing this indexing error in mongo db?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, compiler-errors

I've created 3 indexes based on several json files of Yelp that I imported into my mongodb.

```
> db.review.createIndex({"text":"text"})
{
    "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
    "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
    "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
    "ok" : 1
}
> db.business.createIndex({"categories":"text"})
{
    "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
    "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
    "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
    "ok" : 1
}
> db.business.createIndex({"attributes":"text"})
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Index with pattern: { _fts: \"text\", _ftsx: 1 } already exists with different options",
    "code" : 85
```

Basically I'm trying to create 3 indexes to make count function faster in my mongodb.

What does `"errmsg" : "Index with pattern: { _fts: \"text\", _ftsx: 1 } already exists with different options"` means?

Should I pick a differente thing as attribute, or should I drop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MongoDB (as of v3.4) only allows one text index per collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/index-text/#restrictions)

In your `business` collection, you already built a text index on `categories`. So, the second text index, on `attributes`, will fail.

Comment: hey sir can you answer my other question? I'm lost on that, how can I built an index with two or more collections, I want to count items that are in both collections that fit the requirement.

Comment: @NewSQLguy : An index only works on one collection. If you want to count items from two different collections, you will need to do one query on each collection and combine the results in your application.

Comment: if you play around with text indexes, you will very likely try out different variations, but you have to delete old text indexes before using new ones!